# Object with highest count in a Groovy list

Tags: groovy, closure

I have a list of `Parcel` objects and am trying to write a closure that picks the parcel object with highest count:

```
class Parcel { 
int id, 
int count,
String sender,
String recipient 
Parcel(int _id, int _count) {
 id = _id
 count = _count 
 } 
}

def parcels = [new parcel(1,5), new parcel(2,1), new parcel(3,3), new parcel(4,2), new parcel(5,4) ]
```

I have tried the below code which works fine:

```
parcels.sort{it.count}
parcels.reverse().first()
```

Is there a better way to pick the parcel with the highest count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could obviously try `parcels.max{it.count}`.

`max` and other useful operations on Groovy Collections are explained in the following article:
https://groovy.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Collections